# wordpress schedule database entry

Tags: wordpress

i am new to wordpress want to know  where it stores schedule data. i have seen in post instead of published data status shows future and same is being published in that time and status changed from future to published. i changed the status of few post directly in database to future and changed the time of post_date and post_date_gmt to future time but it was not published and status remain same as future.
i think wordpress stores data somewhere else in some other tables and it fires cron based on that table. any help will be great

cron vlaues in wp_options are

```
a:8:
{i:1467778980;
a:1:{s:19:"nxs_querypost_event";
a:1:{s:32:"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a";
a:3:{s:8:"schedule";s:11:"nxsreposter";s:4:"args";
a:0:{}s:8:"interval";i:90;}}}i:1467781670;
a:1:{s:16:"nxs_hourly_event";
a:1:{s:32:"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a";
a:3:{s:8:"schedule";s:6:"hourly";s:4:"args";
a:0:{}s:8:"interval";i:3600;}}}i:1467781924;
a:1:{s:24:"akismet_scheduled_delete";
a:1:{s:32:"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a";
a:3:{s:8:"schedule";s:5:"daily";s:4:"args";
a:0:{}s:8:"interval";i:86400;}}}i:1467787812;
a:3:{s:16:"wp_version_check";
a:1:{s:32:"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a";
a:3:{s:8:"schedule";s:10:"twicedaily";s:4:"args";
a:0:{}s:8:"interval";i:43200;}}s:17:"wp_update_plugins";
a:1:{s:32:"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a";
a:3:{s:8:"schedule";s:10:"twicedaily";s:4:"args";
a:0:{}s:8:"interval";i:43200;}}s:16:"wp_update_themes";
a:1:{s:32:"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a";
a:3:{s:8:"schedule";s:10:"twicedaily";s:4:"args";
a:0:{}s:8:"interval";i:43200;}}}i:1467791880;
a:1:{s:20:"wp_maybe_auto_update";
a:1:{s:32:"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a";
a:3:{s:8:"schedule";s:10:"twicedaily";s:4:"args";
a:0:{}s:8:"interval";i:43200;}}}i:1467817919;
a:1:{s:19:"wp_scheduled_delete";
a:1:{s:32:"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a";
a:3:{s:8:"schedule";s:5:"daily";s:4:"args";
a:0:{}s:8:"interval";i:86400;}}}i:1467820230;
a:1:{s:30:"wp_scheduled_auto_draft_delete";
a:1:{s:32:"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a";
a:3:{s:8:"schedule";s:5:"daily";s:4:"args";
a:0:{}s:8:"interval";i:86400;}}}s:7:"version";i:2;}
```

Comment: WordPress cron isn't a true cron. It checks if there's something to run when someone visits any page - so if you have no visits, nothing will be updated. The start of [this post](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/10/schedule-events-using-wordpress-cron/) explains it in more detail. [This post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84424/scheduled-posts-and-wp-cron-why-dont-scheduled-posts-publish-if-too-old) on the WordPress stack exchange implies there's a 24 hour window, so if you don't have any visitors on the day you need the cron to run, it may never run (haven't checked that).

Comment: @Hobo that i already know. i asked something else you have writtten completely differenct thing

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood.  Thought you were looking for a possible reason cron wasn't firing.  I'll add an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR** the values are in the wp_options table, where option_name = 'cron'.

---

Posts are moved from future to published using WordPress cron, you're right.  When you schedule a post for future publication, WordPress updates the "cron" entry in the options table (`wp_options` by default, though that will vary if you've changed the table prefix).

It [adds a `publish_future_post` entry](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/post.php#L5744) to the stored array (using the [`wp_schedule_single_event()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/cron.php#L8) function).

The actual publishing is done via the [`check_and_publish_future_post()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/post.php#L3500) function.

The value is PHP-serialized, so updating it with a database query might be tricky.

**Edit**

Further to my comment, these are the before (no future posts) and after (one future post) values I see in that table.

Before:

```
'a:4:{i:1467810391;a:3:{s:16:\"wp_version_check\";a:1:{s:32:\"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a\";a:3:{s:8:\"schedule\";s:10:\"twicedaily\";s:4:\"args\";a:0:{}s:8:\"interval\";i:43200;}}s:17:\"wp_update_plugins\";a:1:{s:32:\"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a\";a:3:{s:8:\"schedule\";s:10:\"twicedaily\";s:4:\"args\";a:0:{}s:8:\"interval\";i:43200;}}s:16:\"wp_update_themes\";a:1:{s:32:\"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a\";a:3:{s:8:\"schedule\";s:10:\"twicedaily\";s:4:\"args\";a:0:{}s:8:\"interval\";i:43200;}}}i:1467853602;a:1:{s:19:\"wp_scheduled_delete\";a:1:{s:32:\"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a\";a:3:{s:8:\"schedule\";s:5:\"daily\";s:4:\"args\";a:0:{}s:8:\"interval\";i:86400;}}}i:1467855934;a:1:{s:30:\"wp_scheduled_auto_draft_delete\";a:1:{s:32:\"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a\";a:3:{s:8:\"schedule\";s:5:\"daily\";s:4:\"args\";a:0:{}s:8:\"interval\";i:86400;}}}s:7:\"version\";i:2;}','yes');'
```

After:

```
'a:5:{i:1467802230;a:1:{s:19:\"publish_future_post\";a:1:{s:32:\"c235acd81e1457babc4e93303796723c\";a:2:{s:8:\"schedule\";b:0;s:4:\"args\";a:1:{i:0;i:20;}}}}i:1467810391;a:3:{s:16:\"wp_version_check\";a:1:{s:32:\"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a\";a:3:{s:8:\"schedule\";s:10:\"twicedaily\";s:4:\"args\";a:0:{}s:8:\"interval\";i:43200;}}s:17:\"wp_update_plugins\";a:1:{s:32:\"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a\";a:3:{s:8:\"schedule\";s:10:\"twicedaily\";s:4:\"args\";a:0:{}s:8:\"interval\";i:43200;}}s:16:\"wp_update_themes\";a:1:{s:32:\"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a\";a:3:{s:8:\"schedule\";s:10:\"twicedaily\";s:4:\"args\";a:0:{}s:8:\"interval\";i:43200;}}}i:1467853602;a:1:{s:19:\"wp_scheduled_delete\";a:1:{s:32:\"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a\";a:3:{s:8:\"schedule\";s:5:\"daily\";s:4:\"args\";a:0:{}s:8:\"interval\";i:86400;}}}i:1467855934;a:1:{s:30:\"wp_scheduled_auto_draft_delete\";a:1:{s:32:\"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a\";a:3:{s:8:\"schedule\";s:5:\"daily\";s:4:\"args\";a:0:{}s:8:\"interval\";i:86400;}}}s:7:\"version\";i:2;}'
```

The difference being the `publish_future_post` entry:

```
i:1467802230;a:1:{s:19:\"publish_future_post\";a:1:{s:32:\"c235acd81e1457babc4e93303796723c\";a:2:{s:8:\"schedule\";b:0;s:4:\"args\";a:1:{i:0;i:20;}}}}
```

Comment: i could not find any TL,DR. added cron values in question

Comment: Hmm; wonder if it's a version issue.  If you select that row, add a future post (in the admin), and select again, do you see a difference?

Comment: why am I not surprised that WP would find a terrible way to store this information?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this code to your theme’s functions.php file

```
function wpb_upcoming_posts() { 
        // The query to fetch future posts
        $the_query = new WP_Query(array( 
            'post_status' => 'future',
            'posts_per_page' => 3,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'ASC'
        ));

    // The loop to display posts
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<ul>';
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            $output .= '<li>' . get_the_title() .' ('.  get_the_time('d-M-Y') . ')</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';

    } else {
        // Show this when no future posts are found
        $output .= '<p>No posts planned yet.</p>';
    }

    // Reset post data
    wp_reset_postdata();

    // Return output

    return $output; 
    } 
    // Add shortcode
    add_shortcode('upcoming_posts', 'wpb_upcoming_posts'); 
    // Enable shortcode execution inside text widgets
    add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

Shortcodes:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[upcoming_posts]');?>

[upcoming_posts]
```

Hope so its work

Comment: i am not interested in displaying future post. thx for ur answer that i can do from wp_post status. my intenion is to know where exactly wordpress stores future post data. one i can see directly in wp_post table i tried to change that one but its not posting. so there is something in wp_options so please help to figure it out

Comment: have you check this {wp}_options table under the name 'cron' run query SELECT *
FROM `wp_options`
WHERE `option_name` LIKE '%cron%'

Comment: if not work  add this code functions.php $cron_jobs = get_option( 'cron' );
var_dump($cron_jobs);

Comment: i have posted cron vlaues of wp_options in question

Comment: In your wp_post table where to find posts status "future" then edit it and change the date and time from query save it . it will publish on front end